# What is the general formula for a cylinder in 3D?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Say I have a line in 3D space with the equation:
$$x=x_0+ta\\y=y_0+tb\\z=z_0+tc$$

I know that the euqation of a cylinder in 3D is:
$$(y−z)^2+(z−x)^2+(x−y)^2=3r^2$$
from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875569/simple-geometry-question-equation-of-cylinder)

However this cylinder is on the line: $x=y=z$

Is there any way to find the formula for a cylinder with its central axis on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for a right circular cylinder of radius $r$, having an axis

$ A = P_0 + t a $

where $ a $ is a unit vector, is given by

$\boxed{ ( p - P_0)^T (I - {aa}^T ) (p - P_0) = r^2} $

where $p = [x, y, z]^T $

A special case of this equation is when $P_0 = (0,0,0)$ and $a = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1, 1, 1) $.  In this case,

$ I - {aa}^T = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && - 1 && - 1 \\ -1 && 2 && -1 \\ -1 && -1 && 2 \end{bmatrix}$

So that, the left hand side is

$ \dfrac{1}{3} ( 2 x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 z^2 - 2 x y - 2 x z - 2 y z ) $

which can be factored as

$ \dfrac{1}{3} ( (x - y)^2 + (x - z)^2 + (y - z)^2 ) $

Hence, we get

$ (x - y)^2 + (x - z)^2 + (y - z)^2 = 3 r^2 $

Comment: What is meant by the $I-aa^T$ in $( p - P_0)^T (I - {aa}^T ) (p - P_0) = r^2$
And wouldn't $aa^T$ be equal to $a^(T+1)$

Comment: $T$ means taking the transpose of a vector.  So if $a = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}$ then $a^T = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 && a_2 && a_3 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: The axis $a$ is represented by a column vector, so $a = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (1, 1, 1) $ means $ a = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Then ${a a}^T = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: And finally, $I - {a a}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} - \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && -1 && -1 \\ -1 && 2 && -1 \\ -1 && -1 && 2 \end{bmatrix} $