# Does an Implicit equation for an infinite Cylinder exist ? i.e f(x,y,z)=0

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, mathematical-modeling, quadrics

I wanted to know if the surface for any arbitrary cylinder(infinte or restricted does not matter) can be expressed with an implicit equation, like that for a sphere: $$(X-x)^2 + (Y-y)^2 + (Z-z)^2 = R^2$$ where $(x,y,z)$ are the co-ordinates of the center of the sphere. I know the equation for general quadric surfaces are of the form $$ aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2 +dXY+eYZ+fXZ+gX+hY+iZ+j=0$$

What I want to know is how many of these terms are zero for any arbitrary cylinder or equivalently if the equation has a special form for a cylinder like it does for a plane and for the sphere?

If I assume that a set of points belong to a cylindrical surface, what is the minimum number of points that I need to determine its equation?

I would be happy to explain further if something in my question is unclear.

Comment: I saw this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141593/formula-for-cylinder?newreg=52c6b3d9cb1d47c1aaa3ff0706aa2298) but it only accounts for the specific case if the axis of rotation of the cylinder is of the form **(t,t,t)**

Comment: Do you mean  a circular cylinder or a cylinder with any conic as a basis?

Comment: how to distinguish a cylinder given the general quadric equation is summarized [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticSurface.html)

Comment: @Bernard I mean a circular cylinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the axis of the cylinder is the line through $\vec{x}_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and in the direction of $\vec{v} = (a,b,c)$ with radius $R$, assuming $|\vec{v}| = 1$, we can write the equation of the cylinder as the set of all points $\vec{x} = (x,y,z)$ satisfying:

$$|\vec{x} - \vec{x}_0|^{2} = R^{2} + [(\vec{x} - \vec{x}_0)\bullet \vec{v}]^{2}$$

Comment: Ah, simple pythagoras theorem. thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 - r^2 = 0$$ describes such a cylinder whose axis is the line $(x,y,z) = (h,k,z)$ and has radius $r$.  So for example, $$x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$$ describes an infinite cylinder in $\mathbb R^3$ with axis coinciding with the $z$-axis, and with radius $1$.  Now you might say, "this is just the equation of the unit circle in the plane," and you are right, but it is also the same equation for a cylinder in Euclidean 3-space.  The fact that $z$ does not show up in the equation simply means that the value of $z$ is irrelevant.  This is precisely analogous to the situation in the plane, where I can define a vertical line with an implicit equation such as $$x = 2.$$  This still describes a set of points in $\mathbb R^2$ if we regard this equation as representing a line in the plane.

Now, if you wish to have a less trivial example, it is not hard to think how this could work, much like we can write a general line $y = mx + b$ in the plane, we can generalize a cylinder in $\mathbb R^3$, and all three coordinates $(x,y,z)$ show up in the implicit equation.  For example, $$(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 = 3$$ describes a cylinder in $\mathbb R^3$ whose axis is the line satisfying $x = y = z$ and has radius $1$.  The proof of this fact is left to the reader as an exercise.

In general, the equation of a cylinder with axis joining $(0,0,0)$ to some arbitrary point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ such that $x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2 = 1$ and has radius $r$, is given by $$(y_0 x - x_0 y)^2 + (z_0 y - y_0 z)^2 + (x_0 z - z_0 x)^2 = r^2.$$

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. However your answer still assumes that the cylinder passes through the origin. But a simple translation will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

From the equation in form
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2 +2dxy+2eyz+2fxz+2gx+2hy+2iz+j=0,$$
you can know if the quadric *can* be a cylinder.

For this consider the matrix of the quadratic part of the equation:
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
a&d&f\\ d&b&e \\f&e&c
\end{bmatrix}$$
If $Q$ has rank $2$ and if its non-zero eigenvalues have the same sign, i.e. if the associated quadratic form has signature $(2,0)$ or $(0,2)$, then you know you have either an `elliptic paraboloid` or an `elliptic cylinder`.

The difference between both can be seen only once you've obtained a reduced form of the equation by a change of orthogonal basis, which will be:

- $\dfrac{X^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{Y^2}{b^2}=Z\quad$ (*elliptic paraboloid*),
- $\dfrac{X^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{Y^2}{b^2}=1\quad$ (*elliptic cylinder*).

Comment: I do not have the equation in that form. What I do have are a bunch of points. I need to check if those points form a quadric shape (at the moment only spheres, cylinders and planes as a degenrate case)and if so which one. What I planned was A RANSAC like approach, ie pick points and form a hypothesis (model). Then check that model against other points, like how well it will fits the other points. I was wondering about the number of points needed to define an arbitrary cylinder.

Comment: For  a cylinder I don't know, but to be on a quadric, it's easy: as the quadrics form a projective space of dimension $9$, $9$ points are enough. Then one obtains the matrix associated with this equation, which has to have rank $4$ to be non-degenerate, and the submatrix $Q$ of the quadratic part of the equation.

Comment: That is too much computationally. I think @Alex Zorn's method suits my application better. But thank you for your answer. I did not know that a elliptic paraboloid and an elliptic cylinder generally cannot be distinguished in a quadratic equation.